# Bash Completions "Mashed" Together

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

Recently, my Bash completions (assuming that's what you call the results after a tab, tab) have been messed up, returning all the commands, kind of mashed together.

For example, typing `docker` then tab, tab, I get:

```
me@me[~]: docker builderconfigcontainercontextimagemanifestnetworknodepluginsecretservicestackswarmsystemtrustvolumebuildloginlogoutrunsearchversionscanattachcommitcpcreatediffeventsexecexporthistoryimagesimportinfoinspectkillloadlogspauseportpspullpushrenamerestartrmrmisavestartstatsstoptagtopunpauseupdatewait help
```

A similar thing happens with other commands, like `systemctl`.  As far as I know, nothing has changed about completions or the commands, but something must have.  Perhaps I don't have the right terms to search, but nothing has turned up yet.

Does anyone know what might have caused this?

Comment: Have you changed your `$TERM` environment variable? Read `man stty`.

Comment: Try reinstalling bash-completion. This can be done using your package manager, like sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion

Comment: No changes to `$TERM`, it reports xterm-256color in all the ways I can log in.  Removing `bash-completion` does make the problem go away, though at the cost of tab, tab.  Very odd this is happening